# Jersey ws to return a zip file

Tags: web-services, jersey

I need to read a zip file and send it as a Jersey response.The below code snippet returns a zip file. But the zip file(sample1.zip) cannot be opened as it reports "The archive is either unknown format or damaged." I'm able to other zip files on my machine. Can anyone help me to figure out what the issue could be?

```
@Produces("application/zip")
public Response getFile() {
    StreamingOutput soo = new StreamingOutput() {
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException,
                WebApplicationException {
            try {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("sample.zip");
                InputStream in = zipFile.getInputStream(zipFile
                        .getEntry("test.xml"));
                IOUtils.copy(in, output);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException(e);
            }
        }
    };
    return Response
            .ok()
            .entity(soo)
            .header("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename = sample1.zip").build();

}
```

I've used apache commons io utility (IOUtils) to copy input to ouput .

Answer (score 0):

have you defined the @Provider that's @Produces("application/zip")?
Check the log, and look if a messagebodywriter is needed